# FatFs strange behavior when writing to text file

Tags: pic, sd, datalogger, fat

I wrote a small program with PIC32MX microcontroller that sends data to a txt file in the SD card, then reads the data back from the file and finally  compares the data before sending them with the data after sending them, from the txt file of the SD.

I do this, to check if the bytes are saved/retrieved correctly (or not) to/from the txt file created in the SD card.

Data consist of only two characters, 'G' and 'H' . First I write 500 Bytes of  'G's and then 500 Bytes of 'H's. repeatedly for 10 times and the total number of bytes in the txt file would be 10kB.

Also,  data in the txt file of the SD would appear like this: GGG...HHH...GGG...HHH... etc.
To write these data to the file I use the f_write() function

```
FRESULT f_write (
   FIL* fp,          /* [IN] Pointer to the file object structure */
   const void* buff, /* [IN] Pointer to the data to be written */
   UINT btw,         /* [IN] Number of bytes to write */
   UINT* bw          /* [OUT] Pointer to the variable to return number of bytes written */
);
```

And here lies the problem. When I set the Number of bytes to write, to 1000 bytes(500 'G's and 500 'H's, the result in the txt file is only GGGGG... with no'H's. When I double the number of bytes to write, from 1000 to 2000, only then GGG...HHHH...GGG...HHH sequence appears correctly.

And the question is, why is this happening. Normally the latter (correct) result should occur when I set the exact number of bytes to write, in the function (1000) and not by doubling it(2000)

Any idea why this happens?

Thank you for your time

Comment: something is wrong with your program. perhaps buf is not filled correctly.

Comment: It may to do with the size of the data versus the size of the blocks in the SD card.  Writes smaller than a full SD block may be getting buffered.  Have you tried flushing the writes before doing the reads, or even just writing in chunks the same size as the SD blocks?

Comment: Thank you Guys. What do you mean by flushing the writes? I have two buffers one for sending data to the SD file and one buffer for reading data from that txt

Comment: As crj11 says: To debug it is better to start with complete SD card sectors, most of which are set to 512 bytes.

Comment: ok I will check it out and I'll tell you what happened

Comment: Dump SPI communications to see if all data is properly ordered.

Comment: In ffconf.h of fatfs both #define FF_MIN_SS #define FF_MAX_SS are set to 512 I decreased the buffer size  that sends data to f_write , down to 512. Then I set the number of bytes to be written in f_write, to 512 . But the same thing happened again. Only GGGGGGG...

Comment: I created a small test to check written bytes to the txt of SD. The results are recorded in a second txt file. Although the data in the first file are half the test says that 512 bytes have been evaluated. What is going on here... I am a little confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found It,

Initially I set the buffers as uint16_t because I thought to fill them with integer numbers and then I forgot it and I decided to fill them with characters G and H.

Ok, you could say that characters can be interpreted as decimal values too but, I did not cast  to integer values because I forgot they were of type integer.

So I changed the buffers from uint16_t to char type and now all data are recorded as initially expected. I don't know what happens behind the scene but I assume that it has something to do with memory addresses.. Anyway thank you all for your time.